# Why does Ember Data do a POST for an existing record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After fetching several records from a server, I hand them over to a (array) controller. The array of records is displayed in a table and the order of the records can be modified by drag and drop. After each drop, the `sort` attribute of each record is updated to reflect the new sort order.

Saving the records triggers a `PUT` request for some records and a `POST` request for other records. What could be the cause of this? The odd thing is that the `POST` request includes the record's `id`. I was under the assumption that any record with a valid `id` triggers a `PUT` request.

To be clear, I use Ember Data as the application's model layer.

```
App.ProjectsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['sort'],

  updateSortOrder: function() {
    this.beginPropertyChanges();
    this.forEach(function(project) {
      // UPDATE PROJECT
    }, this);
    this.endPropertyChanges();

    this.forEach(function(project) {
      project.save();
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:** After debugging this issue a bit more, I noticed that Ember Data creates a new record for one of the records, which explains why a `POST` request is fired. However, it isn't clear why a record is created for an existing record with a valid `id`.

Comment: Hmm.. that the `id` is set doesn't mean Ember will per definition assume that it is an existing record (and thus use PUT). I'm curious to see a bit more code/context. If you'd like to create a jsbin, here's a template w/ ember data: http://jsbin.com/ogorab/316/edit.

Comment: That's true, but I meant to say that the `id` is included in the response of the initial fetch, which should be an indication for Ember Data that it is an existing record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data is a fairly complex model layer and the bug I've run into is a result of my inexperience with it.

In one of my models, I created a computed property with a name of `isNew`. I should have picked a better name. Every Ember Data model has a number of methods that return information about the model's state, such as `isSaving`, `isDirty`, `isLoaded`, and ... `isNew`.

By overriding the `isNew` method in my model class, I informed the store when a model was a new record (triggering a `POST` request when saving) or an existing record (triggering a `PUT` request when saving). You can find a complete list of a model's properties [at the Ember website](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html).